# How do I remove previous years from data_select menu? Setting start_date gas zero effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My select menu goes back to 2009. I'd like it have a start year of the current year.

**This isn't working for me.**

```
<%= date_select :date, :format=>'%B %d, %Y %l:%M %p', :start_year => Date.current.year
  %> <br />
```

Todays date shows up by default and this isn't a problem. When I click the year select drop down select I don't want any previous years showing up.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind splitting up your drop down menus into years, months, and days:

`select_year(Date.today, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: 2020)`

Here are the [Rails date helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the best option, but I've done this using [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) and the yearRange attribute